# Docker container terminating automatically

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongodb-replica-set

I am working on a test docker-compose file to run a container with three mongod servers, which form a replica set (One is primary, one is secondary and one is arbiter).

My Dockerfile looks like :-

```
FROM mongo:3.6.2

MAINTAINER Shanty

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat

COPY ./.docker/mongo_scripts /mongo_scripts

RUN chmod +rx /mongo_scripts/*.sh

EXPOSE 27091 27092 27093

ENTRYPOINT ["/mongo_scripts/rs.sh"]
```

and my script looks like :-

```
    #!/bin/bash

# shell script to create a simple mongodb replica set (tested on osx)
mkdir -p /mongosvr/rs-0
mkdir -p /mongosvr/rs-1
mkdir -p /mongosvr/rs-2

mongod --dbpath /mongosvr/rs-0 --bind_ip_all --replSet "demo" --port 27091 --pidfilepath /mongosvr/rs-0.pid 2>&1 &

mongod --dbpath /mongosvr/rs-1 --bind_ip_all --replSet "demo" --port 27092 --pidfilepath /mongosvr/rs-1.pid 2>&1 &

mongod --dbpath /mongosvr/rs-2 --bind_ip_all --replSet "demo" --port 27093 --pidfilepath /mongosvr/rs-2.pid 2>&1 &

# wait a bit for the first server to come up
sleep 5

# call rs.initiate({...})
cfg="{
    _id: 'demo',
    members: [
        {_id: 0, host: 'localhost:27091', 'priority':10},
        {_id: 1, host: 'localhost:27092'},
        {_id: 2, host: 'localhost:27093', arbiterOnly: true}
    ]
}"
mongo localhost:27091 <<EOF
var cfg={
    _id: 'demo',
    members: [
        {_id: 0, host: 'localhost:27091', 'priority':10},
        {_id: 1, host: 'localhost:27092'},
        {_id: 2, host: 'localhost:27093', arbiterOnly: true}
    ]
}
    rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
EOF
```

Its a simple script running three mongod servers, and initialising replica set configuration.
But after the last command is successfully executed, the following
is logged :-

```
bye
I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:55178 (2 connections now open)
```

and my container stops:-

```
mongodb_rs exited with code 0
```

I guess its some issue with setting replica set config, after which some termination command is send....

Comment: Your container terminates when the script terminates.

Comment: This is what im asking.. Why? it doesn't exit if I remove the last command of setting replica set config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that worked as of now is that I put following command at the end of the script:-

```
sleep infinity
```

I still don't know whether its the best way.... Still looking for better solution, or explanation if the current one is the best....

Answer (score 0):

you should not override the `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile cause it might do more stuff for setting up the container from mongo team. Try to replace the ENTRYPOINT with `CMD`

```
CMD ["/mongo_scripts/rs.sh"]
```

Comment: Tried. Didn't work. However, it works with even entry point when I don't add the last command of setting replica set configuration..

Answer (score 0):

Add

> sh -c /bin/bash

at the end of your bash script. It will start a new process bash with a new pid. So your container will not die.

Answer (score 0):

When your script starts a mongod process, it only exists within the scope of the script; so when the script ends, it shuts down each mongod process.

To make them persistent, you need to add the [--fork option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-fork) :

> Enables a [daemon](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-daemon) mode that runs the mongod process in the background. By default mongod does not run as a daemon: typically you will run mongod as a daemon, either by using --fork or by using a controlling process that handles the daemonization process (e.g. as with upstart and systemd).

Comment: @ShubhamGupta What didn't work - can you describe what happened?